# parsing CSV in Javascript and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, csv

So I'm trying to create a basic angular application that parses some CSV input, and fills a table with the parsed data.

You can see a plunker of what I'm trying to achieve here - http://plnkr.co/edit/6QFT4AcV4KpiSG23EdOS

Basically - as you can see - I have a `<textarea>` where the user will paste in some CSV, and the table below should then be filled with the data.

```
<div class="excelArea">
    <textarea name="excelData" ng-model="excelData"></textarea>
</div>
```

This is the javascript I have so far, but I'm struggling with a few things
1. Seperating the email from the name 
2. Pushing the data back into the `$scope.inviteList;`

```
app.controller("InviteController", function($scope) {

    //Initliase objects
    $scope.excelData = "";
    $scope.errorMessage = "";
    $scope.inviteList = [];

    $scope.$watch("excelData", function() {

        var lines, lineNumber, data, length;

        lines = $scope.excelData.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
        lineNumber = 0;

        for (var i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            l = lines[i];
            lineNumber++;
            data = l.split(/\t/);

            var email = ? ? ?
            var name = ? ? ?

            $scope.inviteList.push({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                status: "not sent"
            });

        };

    });

});
```

Some basic information:

The CSV will be two columns (name, email) and will look like this:

```
John Thompson,john@thompson.com
Robin Peters, robin@peters.com
Bill Bob, bill@bob.com
```

Comment: Note that parsing a CSV is not just splitting on the separator, if you want to fully support the CSV format use a 'real' parser (for example http://papaparse.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many problems in your code :

- You could juste use split on your input instead of regexes, it makes everything easier
- Your HTML isn't valid `td` should be inside `tr` and not the other way around
- Your array was never cleared
- Your bindings inside `ng-repeat` didn't use variable `i` defined here : `i in inviteList`
- You should avoid unscoped variables (without `var` keyword) whenever possible

Otherwise, when you split a string, just access the splitted elements through their index.

Corrected code :

JS

```
$scope.$watch("excelData", function() {
    var lines, lineNumber, data, length;
    $scope.inviteList = [];
    lines = $scope.excelData.split('\n');
    lineNumber = 0;
    for (var i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        l = lines[i];

        lineNumber++;
        data = l.split(',');

        var name = data[0];
        var email = data[1];

        $scope.inviteList.push({
            name: name,
            email: email,
            status: "not sent"
        });
    }
});
```

HTML

```
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Email</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="i in inviteList">
      <td>{{i.name}}</td>
      <td>{{i.email}}</td>
      <td>{{i.status}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Your code (especially JS) can still be improved a lot and i encourage you to read docs/tutorials more.

And [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ssq2O3UWkj41AqpGfCGO?p=preview) is the plunker to your working code.

Answer (score 1):

I would create a filter to parse the data and reuse it anywhere I want it to.
Logic:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $filter) {
  $scope.data = 'John Thompson,john@thompson.com\nRobin Peters, robin@peters.com\nBill Bob, bill@bob.com';

  $scope.$watch('data', function(val){
    $scope.inviteList = $filter('csvToObj')(val);
  });
});

app.filter('csvToObj', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var rows = input.split('\n');
    var obj = [];
    angular.forEach(rows, function(val) {
      var o = val.split(',');
      obj.push({
        name: o[0],
        email: o[1],
        status: "not sent"
      });
    });
    return obj;
  };
});
```

**Sample Demo:**http://plnkr.co/edit/SOtMMLft3amlVm4RROd0?p=preview

Comment: Thanks! Works nicely, changes my structure a bit , but this is much better!

Answer (score 1):

When you split a string, the return value is an array.
  I believe that you only have to access the correct indexes of the data array:

```
app.controller("InviteController", function($scope) {

    //Initliase objects
    $scope.excelData = "";
    $scope.errorMessage = "";
    $scope.inviteList = [];

    $scope.$watch("excelData", function() {

        var lines, lineNumber, data, length;

        lines = $scope.excelData.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
        lineNumber = 0;

        for (var i = lines.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

            l = lines[i];
            lineNumber++;
            data = l.split(/\t/);

            var email = data[1];
            var name = data[0];

            $scope.inviteList.push({
                name: name,
                email: email,
                status: "not sent"
            });

        };

    });

});
```